# Which CorePlot version should we use for iOS 8?

Tags: ios8, core-plot

I have an existing app which has been developed for iOS 7 using CorePlot 1.4 and Xcode 5. 
I am now looking to enhance it for iOS 8.

Would you recommend upgrading to the current Core Plot version 1.5 or go with 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official 2.0 release yet, although hopefully we'll have one out soon. There will be some breaking API changes from the 1.x releases. See the [change log](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/release-2.0/documentation/changelog.markdown) for details.

I would recommend upgrading to the 1.5.1 release if you want to stick with the official release packages. Go with the `release-2.0` branch of the code on GitHub if you need some of the new features (e.g., @3x image support for the iPhone 6 Plus). If you do that, you'll be ready for the final 2.0 release whenever it is done.

Comment: I'd add a further comment. If you are think of using Swift, you should definitely go with the release-2.0 branch. I'm doing this for a new project. It's a lot easier than trying to use the main branch and then working through the NSDecimal issues with Swift and core plot